# filtering out similar lines from a log

Tags: algorithm, text, filtering

I'm looking for a very simplistic algorithm to filter out the often repeated lines from a very large log file.
The structure of the entries in the log is mostly unknown. (first I'd like to process the output of systemd's journalctl, but later I'd like to use it to other logs too...)
I cut the first part of the entries (containing the timestamp and host name) and then process the rest of the line. It could contain many variable fields, with process ID, another timestamp, a sequence number etc., with constant strings.
For example, I have many lines like these:

```
anacron[29090]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2018-11-28
anacron[3330]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2018-11-29
anacron[6502]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2018-11-30
anacron[24515]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2018-12-01
anacron[12797]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2018-12-02
```

or these:

```
whoopsie[1827]: [12:29:38] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[1827]: [12:59:22] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[1827]: [12:59:23] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[1827]: [21:22:53] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[2147]: [17:48:49] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[2147]: [17:48:49] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[2147]: [17:48:49] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
```

("many" is greater than a value which will defined later, based on the size of log file)

These are two groups of "similar" lines.
These filterable if I know where are the variable parts of the lines (the process ID, and the date field in the first, the pid and time in the second sample), but I don't know every possible variations. The source is a black box for me. The only sure thing is that, the amount of "fixed" fields is greater than the variables.

I'd like to find them (actually I want to filter out the "noise" from the log), but I have no idea, how to do it. I'm looking for an algorithm, not a tool!

Comment: What have you tried- anything? I suppose what you need is a an array data structure that countains a list of phrases that you want to filter on (i.e daemon, message about something) and a bool flag. You iterate through your log file and check whether the line contains the phrases in your list- if so you set the flag to true and store the current line in a separate  array. When you’re done this array will contain a filtered log list which you can save to a file.

Comment: @auburg I have about 3 million lines in that log with ten or hundred thousands repetition of different lines. My first thought was to compare all lines to all lines, but it is impossible in that amount of data (3M**3M). At now I'm thinking about counting the words' occurrence in the file, assign a "score" to every words, and if the sum (or average?) score of a line is greater than n, then it possibly occurs often -> Found it.  But it doesn't look a secret solution. It could generate false positive findings and could left out lines. IMHO

Comment: Write a code that adds these lines into the Log Table with Columns according to your requirement and then query them according to your need.

Comment: 3 million lines ?! You’ll need to supplement my suggestion with various  text searching  algorithms and experiment. Perhaps turn it  into a sorting problem and use merge sort ?

Comment: @auburg the biggest problem, that the variable parts of the similar lines are on variable positions and to predetermine that pos. is impossible. With a very small log (for example my router's kernel log) it works, because there are very few lines. The main task is to find the variable parts - I have no idea, how can I do it without an AI. :)
With sorting, then manually filtering I've got about 700 thousand lines (sort -> using sed to change the obvious variable fields ([pid] for example) -> uniq)
I can't handle that amount manually...

Comment: All logs have a minimal structure, so that messages can be broken into source, timestamp and actual message. These 3 fields are critical for any tool that is going to try to filter/process logs.

Comment: @tucuxi have you ever seen a longer output of journalctl on a server? ;)

Comment: You are asking for an "algorithm" that can process an unspecified, large amount of lines of text, with no particular structure, to somehow filter out the non-important parts, without any definition of what they look like. As written, this question cannot be answered. Add more details or separate your problem into smaller questions that do have answers.

Comment: @tucuxi it seems to be an impossible mission without the exact knowledge of the entries' structure. For example: ':' is a separator. Really? It is the part of IPv6 addresses too... If I split a line to words and use : as field separator, then I break IPv6 addresses, although I want to use IPv6 addresses as one word...

Answer (score 0):

The statement is ambiguous: how similar is similar? What is the input and the expected output?. Unless you can answer these questions (ideally by editing the question), any answer will contain a lot of guesswork.

Lets go for the low-hanging fruit:

1. N (>1) **consecutive lines** that differ only in small amounts of time can be safely condensed into 1 line, with a **`x N` multiplier** at the end.
2. The sources of lines are probably very limited (probably less than 100). The number of different messages per source is also limited: a daemon typically will report on, say, startup, end-of-operations, and a few very-occasional misc messages. You want to **identify the top message sources** and the top **messages-per-source** to **toggle** them on-demand.
3. Filtering a lot of log messages is somewhat akin to filtering a dump of traffic on a network. How do the network guys make sense of that? **Do what wireshark&co do**: to make sense of large amounts of heterogeneous data, allow interactive querying & filtering. A one-step command-line tool will lose the big picture.

Now on to actual algorithms:

1. Can be implemented in a single pass:

   ```
    start with an empty line
    read a line
    if different from previous line,
      output previous line; and if found multiple times, its multiplicity
      store it, with multiplicity 1
    otherwise
      increase multiplicity of saved line
   ```
2. requires something more sophisticated, but can be approximated in O(N log N), for instance with:

   ```
    sort all lines together (ignoring the time fields)
    calculate distance between consecutive lines
    find a threshold that gives you 90% of all lines grouped into, say, 10 groups
       (you will want to fiddle with the % and group-count to find settings that
        work for your application).
    allow filtering out chosen categories
   ```
3. requires a full-fledged log analysis application, of which there are many.

Comment: The first implementation is simple, but doesn't work: cat logfile.txt | sort | uniq -c (yes, I know, I've asked algorithm, not a tool, but it is the simplest description that algorithm)

2nd: the problem with it, that variable fields' content is really variable. Not just time or date. It could be anything.

3rd: it is the target :) I want to write a short app, which can filter the logs on my machine, ignoring the common lines, including boot messages, logins of ordinary users (but not the rarely used ones) etc.

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it is more understandable... (or not?)